# Unable to Increase Cloud SQL Storage

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Currently we have 4 Cloud SQL instance. We have problem with 1 latest instance, we apply changes to increase our instance Storage but it is not applied. The other instance is normal, we can directly increase the storage.

Anyone also have this kind of issue ?
All help are really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Also having this issue. Having to wait 5 days just to set up a role-based support account to fix this and then god knows how long just to get the actual support! Terrible customer service.

Comment: Does the error still persist? Could you specify what database management system are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQL Server)?